# Select and Update all matching Documents

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to do the following and any help would be appreciated.
Say you make a search and 100,000 documents match.
We would like to increment a counter in each document that matched. Then at the same time select the first page say the first 50.

Can this be done in one operation or may be a parallel scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a multi search query for such kind of maneuver:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Basically you add several queries in a single multi search which is parallelized on the ES side, and returns a list of responses per each query.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any idea how to do that using NEST?

Comment: @user2981411, I haven't touched the NEST, but I see there's a client for it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html. You can try it probably.

Comment: Many thanks. Need a little more assistance as we are new to ES. But thanks anyway.

Comment: i think for the increment counter you will have to do - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Update by query using NEST.Let me know if you still facing any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The update and query results in 2 operations, which bears heavy load on the server everytime a search is made. Is there any way to do this is one operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update by query to do this :

```
{
 "script": { 
     // fieldName is field you want to increment in document
    "source": "ctx._source.fieldName=params.val", // counter increment by when query match
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
        "i": 0,
        "val": i+1,
    }
},
"query": {
      // your match condition
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The update and query results in 2 operations, which bears heavy load on the server everytime a search is made. Is there any way to do this is one operation.